# Parsing multipart request on Python server

Tags: python, post, server, multipartform-data, multipart

I am struggling with a problem with parsing multipart request on Python. I've created a server using `http.server` and trying to handle such requests as GET, POST ans POST multipart. GET and POST are Ok, but when I try to extract data from multipart requset I'm getting this:

```
line 220, in parse_multipart
    headers['Content-Length'] = pdict['CONTENT-LENGTH']
KeyError: 'CONTENT-LENGTH'
```

My purpose is to get an image through multipart request.

Here's the piece of code I'm using:

```
  def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            print("multipart")
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
            pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], "utf-8")
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
               fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict) # the problem is here
        else:
            print("no-multipart")
            messagecontent = "messagecontent"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTTP 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) requires a message with a body - in this case the incoming POST request - to have a content-length or transfer-encoding header.

The cgi module expects that the request will have a `content-length` header, and is crashing because it isn't present.

The request is malformed, so if you're not generating the request yourself your server should catch the exception and return a 400 Bad Request response in this situation.  If you are generating the request yourself, you need to provide a content-length header.